# Groupby count only when a certain value is present in one of the column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe similar to the below mentioned database:

`+------------+-----+--------+
 |    time    | id  | status |
 +------------+-----+--------+
 | 1451606400 | id1 | Yes    |
 | 1451606400 | id1 | Yes    |
 | 1456790400 | id2 | No     |
 | 1456790400 | id2 | Yes    |
 | 1456790400 | id2 | No     |
 +------------+-----+--------+`

I'm grouping by all the columns mentioned above and i'm able to get the count in a different column named `'count'` successfully using the below command:

`df.groupby(['time','id', 'status']).size().reset_index(name='count')`

But I want the count in the above dataframe only in those rows with `status = 'Yes'` and rest should be `'0'`

Desired Output:

`+------------+-----+--------+---------+
 |    time    | id  | status | count   |
 +------------+-----+--------+---------+
 | 1451606400 | id1 | Yes    |       2 |
 | 1456790400 | id2 | Yes    |       1 |
 | 1456790400 | id2 | No     |       0 |
 +------------+-----+--------+---------+`

I tried to count for `status = 'Yes'` with the below code:

`df[df['status']== 'Yes'].groupby(['time','id','status']).size().reset_index(name='count')`

which obviously gives me those rows with `status = 'Yes'` and discarded the rest. I want the discarded ones with `count = 0`

Is there any way to get the result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and for count `sum` boolena `True` values proccesses like `1`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['time','id','status'])
         .apply(lambda x: (x['status']== 'Yes').sum())
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Or create new column and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(A=df['status']=='Yes')
         .groupby(['time','id','status'])['A']
         .sum()
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Very similar solution with no new column, but worse readable a bit:

```
df1 = ((df['status']=='Yes')
        .groupby([df['time'],df['id'],df['status']])
        .sum()
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index(name='count'))

print (df)
         time   id status  count
0  1451606400  id1    Yes      2
1  1456790400  id2     No      0
2  1456790400  id2    Yes      1
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, Thanks for answering... one again! :) I went ahead with the first one and it worked like a charm. I'll have the other solutions in my mind and I'll try out if the first one doesn't work out well.

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - You are welcome! Second solution should be a bit faster in big DataFrame.

Comment: I'm not able to apply transform in the above solution to push results to original dataframe. The results in a new column with the conditions above mentioned should be in the original dataframe, not the dataframe resulted by groupby. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - Can you explain more? Do you need original columns and create new column by output data? Like `df['new'] = (df.assign(A=df['status']=='Yes')
         .groupby(['time','id','status'])['A']
         .transform('sum')
         .astype(int)
         .reset_index(name='count'))`

Comment: Yes, I want compute the results and put back the results to the parent dataframe. Also, I'm trying the above solution for results and I'm not getting the right values in the parent dataframe.

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - Can you explain more? Why it not working?

Comment: @jazreal: The transform solution in the above comment is working fine. In my case where I said the results are not proper, I was supposed to perform count  first and cumulative sum after that. So, I didn't make a clear notice of that at first. 

Also, I'm getting 2 columns from the above transform command one of them is index and the second one is count. How to get only count?

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - ops, `.reset_index(name='count')` is necessary removing

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a slightly different output format, you can [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1451606400]*2 + [1456790400]*3,
                   'id': ['id1']*2 + ['id2']*3,
                   'status': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']})

res = pd.crosstab([df['time'], df['id']], df['status'])

print(res)

status          No  Yes
time       id          
1451606400 id1   0    2
1456790400 id2   2    1
```

The result is a more *efficient* way to store your data as you don't repeat your index in a separate row for every "Yes" / "No" category.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `crosstab` but if I find anything that requires that, i'll definitely look out for this answer.