# Groupby and count only how many times customer was called at specific point of time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

my problem is closely related to [Groupby count only when a certain value is present in one of the column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153703/groupby-count-only-when-a-certain-value-is-present-in-one-of-the-column-in-panda).

Let's say I have a dataframe which is sorted by `not_unique_id` and `date_of_call`.

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=8, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "unique_id": ["K0", "K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "K5", "K6","K7"],
    "not_unique_id": ["A000", "A111", "A222", "A222", "A222", "A222", "A222","A333"],
    "date_of_call": rng,
    "customer_reached": [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
    }
    ) 
df.sort_values(['not_unique_id','date_of_call'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # reset index

df.head(10)
```

[image]

Now I want to add a new column which tells me, how often the customer was called successfully in the past. In other words: count how many times to customer was reached in the past and save result in new column. For the provided example, this would be the result:

[image]

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all datetimes are unique and sorted you can change order by indexing first and then aggregate custom function with `shift` and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last replace missing values and convert column to integers:

```
df['new'] = (df.iloc[::-1]
               .groupby('not_unique_id')['customer_reached']
               .apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
               .fillna(0)
               .astype(int))
print (df)
  unique_id not_unique_id date_of_call  customer_reached  new
0        K7          A333   2015-03-03                 1    0
1        K6          A222   2015-03-02                 1    3
2        K5          A222   2015-03-01                 1    2
3        K4          A222   2015-02-28                 1    1
4        K3          A222   2015-02-27                 1    0
5        K2          A222   2015-02-26                 0    0
6        K1          A111   2015-02-25                 0    0
7        K0          A000   2015-02-24                 1    0
```

Or if possible change order:

```
df.sort_values(['not_unique_id','date_of_call'], inplace=True)


df['new'] = (df.groupby('not_unique_id')['customer_reached']
               .apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
               .fillna(0)
               .astype(int))
print (df)
  unique_id not_unique_id date_of_call  customer_reached  new
0        K0          A000   2015-02-24                 1    0
1        K1          A111   2015-02-25                 0    0
2        K2          A222   2015-02-26                 0    0
3        K3          A222   2015-02-27                 1    0
4        K4          A222   2015-02-28                 1    1
5        K5          A222   2015-03-01                 1    2
6        K6          A222   2015-03-02                 1    3
7        K7          A333   2015-03-03                 1    0
```